# Calculate remaining percentage in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'source': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'Z', 'Z'], 
                   'target':['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'W', 'X'], 
                   'revenue_pct':[0.1, 0.15, 0.12, 0.05, 0.4, 0.2], 
                   'year':[2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2020, 2021]})
```

I would like to add rows to this dataframe showing the remaining value to reach 100% in the `revenue_pct` column. This remaining value should be calculated according to both the `source` and the `year`. In short, the outcome should look like:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'source': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'], 
                   'target':['B', 'C', 'D', 'unknown', 'E', 'unknown', 'W', 'unknown', 'X', 'unknown'], 
                   'revenue_pct':[0.1, 0.15, 0.12, 0.63, 0.05, 0.95, 0.4, 0.6, 0.2, 0.8], 
                   'year':[2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021]})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can aggregate `sum` per both columns with subtract `1` from right side by [`Series.rsub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rsub.html), add column `target` and append to original `DataFrame` with sorting by `year`s:

```
out = (pd.concat([df, 
                  df.groupby(['source','year'])['revenue_pct']
                    .sum()
                    .rsub(1)
                    .reset_index()
                    .assign(target='unknown')]).sort_values('year', ignore_index=True))
print (out)
  source   target  revenue_pct  year
0      A        B         0.10  2010
1      A        C         0.15  2010
2      A        D         0.12  2010
3      A  unknown         0.63  2010
4      A        E         0.05  2011
5      A  unknown         0.95  2011
6      Z        W         0.40  2020
7      Z  unknown         0.60  2020
8      Z        X         0.20  2021
9      Z  unknown         0.80  2021
```

I think slowier alternative is append new rows per groups in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
def f(x):
    x.loc[-1] = x.iloc[0]
    x.loc[-1, 'target'] = 'unknown'
    x.loc[-1, 'revenue_pct'] += 1 - x['revenue_pct'].sum()
    return x


out = df.groupby(['source','year']).apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)
print (out)
  source   target  revenue_pct  year
0      A        B         0.10  2010
1      A        C         0.15  2010
2      A        D         0.12  2010
3      A  unknown         0.63  2010
4      A        E         0.05  2011
5      A  unknown         0.95  2011
6      Z        W         0.40  2020
7      Z  unknown         0.60  2020
8      Z        X         0.20  2021
9      Z  unknown         0.80  2021
```